# drools: rules executed more than one time

Tags: drools

I am trying hands on at the Drools rule engine , I am quite a beginner.

I have the following rules in place in a single rule file:

```
rule "A stand alone rule" 
salience 2
no-loop
when
    $account : Account()
    Account($account.balance>100)
then
    System.out.println("balance>100");
    System.out.println($account.getBalance());
    System.out.println($account.getCustomer().getName());    
end

rule "A second Rule"
salience 1
no-loop
when
    $account : Account()
    Account($account.balance<100)
then
    System.out.println("balance<100");
    System.out.println($account.getBalance());
    System.out.println($account.getCustomer().getName());
end
```

In the StatefulKnowledgeSession I am passing TWO accounts , one with balance 15000 another with balance 15 ,

```
Account account=new Account(7l,15000l);
        Account account1=new Account(5l,15l);

        Customer customer = new Customer("Samrat", 28, "Sector51", account);
        Customer customer1 = new Customer("Alexi", 28, "Sector50", account1);
        account.setCustomer(customer);
        account1.setCustomer(customer1);
        session.insert(account);
        session.insert(account1);

        session.fireAllRules();
```

**According to me the expected result should be that each rule should be fired only once and the corresponding object should be printed.**

But the result I am getting is :

```
balance>100
15000
Samrat
balance>100
15000
Samrat
balance<100
15
Alexi
balance<100
15
Alexi
```

I am not able to understand why each rule is running twice ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using multiple patterns (and not specifying any relation between them) will create a full Cartesian product (just like a select on multiple tables without a join clause).
So, the rule:

```
rule A
when
    Account()
    Account()
then
    ...
end
```

will be activated N^2 times for N objects of type Account.
One solution could be to use the magic field 'this' to specify that the second account is the same as the first one:

```
rule A
when
    $a: Account()
    Account(this == $a)
then
    ...
end
```

But, going back to your example, I think you don't even need to use 2 different patterns. You could rewrite your rules as following:

```
rule "A stand alone rule" 
salience 2
no-loop
when
    $account: Account(balance>100)
then
    System.out.println("balance>100");
    System.out.println($account.getBalance());
    System.out.println($account.getCustomer().getName());    
end

rule "A second Rule"
salience 1
no-loop
when
    $account: Account(balance<100)
then
    System.out.println("balance<100");
    System.out.println($account.getBalance());
    System.out.println($account.getCustomer().getName());
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Bang on ! this fixed it !

Answer (score 2):

I was comparing two objects of same class and was wondering why the rules are getting fired multiple times. However after reading explanation from Esteban Aliverti I thought that my rule might also be creating Cartesian product.

So I replaced "and" from the rules to "," and it worked perfectly. However, I could not understand why "and" was creating Cartesian product.

Earlier my rule was --

```
rule "Rule 1"
    when
       $first : RuleC() and
       second : RuleC(this != $first) and
           RuleC($first.outcome < outcome) and 
           RuleC($first.target == target)
    then
        System.out.println("The rule has been fired ");
end
```

Later my rule became (And it is working absolutely fine) --

```
rule "Rule 1"
    when
       $first : RuleC() and
       second : RuleC(this != $first, $first.outcome < outcome, $first.target == target)
    then
        System.out.println("The rule has been fired ");
end
```

Comment: In the first rule every pattern will be matched for every RuleC object in your working memory and if the constraints match the rule will fire. As in "if there is a RuleC object (first) and there is a RuleC object for which outcome < first.outcome and there is a RuleC object for which target is first.target then fire".